# QuickSight cannot find RDS instance in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-quicksight

I have an RDS cluster in a VPC. I have configured access to it for QuickSight as described in this guide:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-redshift-private-connection/

However, even after configuring the VPC connection as described there, when I try to create the data source, the data source creation screen says:

> Instance ID is required
>
> No available instances in this region for this account

And validation is not possible (does not work?), saying "Not validated".

Has anyone faced this? From what I see the subnets and security groups are configured as needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this was confusing and a huge waste of time, but make sure to choose the "Aurora" connector when creating the data source, not the "RDS" one.

The "Aurora" one, once properly configured, could be validated and the connection worked almost immediately.